# Vue js datatable not working after manually reloading page

Tags: datatables, vuejs2

I'm using datatable in my vue SPA and it is working fine, but when I reload page manually provides this error `[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function"`. Datatable is being initialized in mounted hook. Data are from ajax request.

This is how I'm initializing datatable in mounted hook

```
    $(".table").DataTable()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I made a wrapper component for jQuery DataTables, maybe it will help you: https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net

Answer (score 0):

To verify that this is not a *loading order issue*, put it in a `timer` or `nextTick` to debug.  If it resolves, you will need to ensure you find a way to wait for the library to load first.

```
this.$nextTick(()=> {
 $(".table").DataTable()
})
```

```
setTimeout(()=> {
 $(".table").DataTable()
}, 2000)
```